# Laravel Detected Object as Array: Trying to get property 'title' of non-object

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, session-state

I have problem when passing the retrieved data to the view (`using redirect()->back()-with()`)

I have a method in my controller, after the data retrieved, I make new variable called `$data` and send it to the view, like this

```
$message = Message::find($request->id);

$data    = [
    "{$do}Modal"   => "{$do}Modal",
    'msg'           => $message
];

return redirect()->back()->with($data);
```

Then, in my view, I need to initiate new variable for the data, `$msg`. But I got an error that says the variable is an array when I want to show it.

```
@php
    $msg = Session::get('msg')
@endphp

{{ is_object($msg) }} // it shows 1 ($msg is an object)
{{ $msg->id }} // the error message shown up
{{ $msg['id'] }} // shows the id
```

My first intension is to show up the id, title, etc **as an object**, but I only can show the values as an array.
When I did `var_dump($msg)`, a got this output:

```
            object(App\Models\Message)#200 (26) {
  ["fillable":protected]=>
  array(4) {
    [0]=>
    string(5) "title"
    [1]=>
    string(4) "body"
    [2]=>
    string(8) "password"
    [3]=>
    string(5) "image"
  }
  ["connection":protected]=>
  string(5) "mysql"
  ["table":protected]=>
  string(8) "messages"
  ["primaryKey":protected]=>
  string(2) "id"
  ["keyType":protected]=>
  string(3) "int"
  ["incrementing"]=>
  bool(true)
  ["with":protected]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["withCount":protected]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["perPage":protected]=>
  int(15)
  ["exists"]=>
  bool(true)
  ["wasRecentlyCreated"]=>
  bool(false)
  ["attributes":protected]=>
  array(7) {
    ["id"]=>
    int(101)
    ["title"]=>
    string(19) "Tes ketiga hari ini"
    ["body"]=>
    string(18) "sfkafaf
afaf
afa"
    ["created_at"]=>
    string(19) "2019-12-03 11:20:56"
    ["updated_at"]=>
    string(19) "2019-12-03 11:39:29"
    ["password"]=>
    string(60) "$2y$10$hSTdJZN24aIddOjrGMmUceYN1cPFvLM.IjCcEL/BPb/4C6ayk12va"
    ["image"]=>
    string(91) "kala-gotongan-dan-semut-sadulur-pantang-kubur-jenazah-ini-alasannya_m_39626_1575343256.jpeg"
  }
  ["original":protected]=>
  array(7) {
    ["id"]=>
    int(101)
    ["title"]=>
    string(19) "Tes ketiga hari ini"
    ["body"]=>
    string(18) "sfkafaf
afaf
afa"
    ["created_at"]=>
    string(19) "2019-12-03 11:20:56"
    ["updated_at"]=>
    string(19) "2019-12-03 11:39:29"
    ["password"]=>
    string(60) "$2y$10$hSTdJZN24aIddOjrGMmUceYN1cPFvLM.IjCcEL/BPb/4C6ayk12va"
    ["image"]=>
    string(91) "kala-gotongan-dan-semut-sadulur-pantang-kubur-jenazah-ini-alasannya_m_39626_1575343256.jpeg"
  }
  ["changes":protected]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["casts":protected]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["dates":protected]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["dateFormat":protected]=>
  NULL
  ["appends":protected]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["dispatchesEvents":protected]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["observables":protected]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["relations":protected]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["touches":protected]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["timestamps"]=>
  bool(true)
  ["hidden":protected]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["visible":protected]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["guarded":protected]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(1) "*"
  }
}
```

Comment: You are passing array in `with` so you can only access as array in view.

Comment: @Prashant Deshmukh..... Hmm, I though `with` can be use to send an object. And my friend can sent an object, although the code is same with mine. He doesn't know what is happening, either

Answer (score 1):

Hi i created this same code,so i if you doing something like this :

```
    $message=Test::find(1);

    $data    = [
        "Modal"   => "Modal",
        'msg'           => $message
    ];

    return redirect()->back()->with($data);
```

In the view after dd($msg) you should see this :
[image]

Can you edit your post and show as what dd return in your code?

Edit: So this should work

```
$msg = Session::get('msg');
dd($msg->title);
```

Comment: omg, thanks, I realize that the error happens because `$msg` doesn't have value (because it was loaded on modal, wich is in one page)